# magento 1.9.0.1 shows Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page. after cancel the order

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9

In magento 1.9.0.1 when I try to cancel the order is redirect to dashboard and show this error :

Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

Comment: check console and log error

Comment: you try disable this module and after check

Comment: @MohitPatel i have check that by disable this module and still the same issue